# Stop javascript execution if content is not shown

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a div that contains a javascript that updates the div each X seconds, but when i replace the div's content with another context, i want the javascript to stop because it returns the old content back and overrides the current content.
how can i make javascript stop under those conditions ?

```
 <li><%= link_to "Run task", { :controller => "tasks_runner", :action => "task_form"}, {:remote => TRUE} %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "Monitor tasks", { :controller => "tasks_runner", :action => "monitor_tasks"}, {:remote => TRUE} %></li>

 <div class="content-module-main" id='task_runner_content'> </div>
```

Each link updates the div's contents. my problem is, that the seconds link updates the div with a table content and with a script that updates the table (updates task_runner_content content), and when i click on the first link, after X seconds the content is overridden with the seconds link's content because of the JavaScript.

the update script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(window).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/tasks_runner/monitor_tasks",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "script"
    });
  }, 3000); //in 3 seconds from now 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: But how are we supposed to help if no code provided?

Comment: Do you have a javascript file, or is the action performed with ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a setInterval or setTimeout to update the contents (and it sounds like you are), you would merely clear the timer in the function that changes the context, like so:

```
function update(){
    $('somediv').html('some value');
}

var _timer = setInterval(update, 1000);

function replaceContext(){
    $('somediv').html('new context');
    clearInterval(_timer);
}
```

Comment: but how can i access the _timer if i am using it the way i showed ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you must be using [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to replace the div's content.

```
X = 3000 //number of miliseconds of your interval
I = setInterval(function(){
     console.log("updating div");
}, X);
```

The solution is to stop the interval `I` when another action is performed. You can use [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) as follows:

```
clearInterval(I);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <div id="d1">1</div>
        <div id="d2">div 2 content</div>

        <button type="button" id="change">Click to change the content</button>

        <script>

            var t=1;
            var timer=setInterval(function()

            {
                $("#d1").html(t);
                t++;

            },1000)

            $("#change").click(function()
            {

                window.clearInterval(timer)
                $("#d1").html($("#d2").html());

            });



        </script>
```